# Code not working in Visual Studios Code (VScode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Good day,

I just installed Visual Studio Code (vscode) in my computer just a day ago.
I am new to JavaScript but I came across some code and wanted to test it in it.

The line of codes work well if I use Chrome Console, but for the moment I place it in my just installed vscode, it does not give any response.

Here is the code I am testing:

```
var fruit = 'Banana';
fruit.slice(0, 2);
// Outcome: "Ba"
```

But If I change the code to something else, say:

```
var fruit = "Banana";
console.log(fruit.slice(0, 2));
```

then it works,

Can someone please tell me why the first line of code did not work in Visual Studio Code (vscode)?

Thanks,
Manny

Comment: VSCode isn't the same as a browser console. If you want to print something to the console, you need to tell it to do that. Browsers run a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop) for your convenience.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works. `fruit.slice(0, 2);` returns "Ba", but you're not assigning the returned value to a variable or doing anything with it, that's why you may think that the code isn't working.

```
var fruit = 'Banana';
var sliced = fruit.slice(0, 2);
// sliced is now equal to 'Ba'. 
// If your program ended here, you wouldn't see anything on the console though.
// So far, this is equivalent to your first example.

console.log(sliced);
// Now we're just logging the value of sliced, and we will see 'Ba' in the console.
// Now, this block of code is equivalent to your second example.
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @Manny, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!